# Sitecore 7.2 - Bucket Items getting unpublished automatically

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.2, sitecore-mvc

I have an installation of Sitecore 7.2 running on ASP.NET MVC.

My issue is that I have converted one of my pages into a Item Bucket.

I then create a bunch of bucketable items (posts/pages) underneath and publish.

They show up just fine after publishing, but after a certain period of time or so.... these bucketable items get automatically unpublished and deleted from the "web" database.

I don't know what process is unpublishing these items, and it's driving me insane.  The parent bucket is still there with all the items in the master database in an unpublished state.

Comment: I just ran into something strange.  I created another new item and approved it via my workflow which published the item.  Not more than 5 minutes later, it got deleted from the web and master databases.  I got this when I clicked on the item that still shows in the tree.

"The selected item could not be found.  It may have been deleted by another user."

Answer (score 0):

When you say "in an unpublished state", does this mean they are not in the final approval state of their workflow? Items cannot publish unless they have a version in the final approval state.

(If that is not what you meant, I apologize)

Automated publishing can occur a number of ways, so you may want to check your /sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx to see if the scheduled publish agent is configured to run. You'll also see what interval it is currently configured to run at. This would explain why changes happen in your web database without you triggering a manual publish. You can also check the log files to see if the publish agent is running.

Finally, check the publishing change restrictions to see if your bucketed items have 'end dates' specified for the item or version. These would cause the item to be unpublishable. You should see a warning in content editor to that effect if a version cannot be published.

Comment: These are all items in final state of approval in workflow.  When I publish them... they show up in the web database.  This is the case for a short while.  After a certain period of time... something is deleting them from the web database and putting it back into unpublished state.

Comment: I also didn't set any "end dates" on the items.  I created new items based off my custom bucketable template. I didn't run into unpublishable issue warnings in the content editor.  I will check publishing agent in config to see if there is anything there.  This is only happening to bucketable items.  Regular content tree items are unaffected.